# How to create relative symlink in Java NIO.2?

Tags: java, nio

In linux we can create relative symlinks.

```
 ln -s targetfile symlink
```

In java NIO.2

```
Files.createSymbolicLink(symlink, targetfile);
```

this code not working with relative paths.

Comment: What's the problem to use absolute paths or Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ln -s bla-blah")?

Comment: Please elaborate on "does not work with relative paths". `Files.createSymbolicLink(FileSystems.getDefault().getPath("lnk"), FileSystems.getDefault().getPath("target"))` works as expected, creating `lnk -> target` in the current directory.

Comment: @Taras Exactly using that code. But I need cross platform support.

Comment: @Taras if I copy to another location absolute paths won't work.

Comment: @dhke below code has 2 parameters. 3rd parameter is current directory. current directory required because I need relative symlink. But NIO API has no alternative method.
 
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"ln", "-s", "myfile", "link"}, null, new File("/home/user/test/"));

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Below is the code to give relative path while creating Symbolic links in order to make it accessible in cross platform environments.

```
Path source = Paths.get("D:\\A\\B\\C\\D\\E\\F\\G\\a.mp4"); // original file's absolute path
Path link = Paths.get("D:\\A\\B\\C\\D\\E\\F\\H\\I\\a.mp4"); // symbolic link's absolute path
Path relativeSrc = link.getParent().relativize(source); // relative path of original file from symbolic link

link.getParent().toFile().mkdirs(); // create the directory hierarchy if any folder is not available 
Files.createSymbolicLink(link, reativeSrc); // create symbolic link.
```

Hope this will help :)

Answer (score 2):

Files.createSymbolicLink(destination, targetDirectory.**relativize**(targetfile));